# Failing to run Fitnesse HelloWorld Program

Tags: fitnesse

I am trying the HelloWorld mentioned in http://gojko.net/fitnesse/book/. I am actually stuck with that, I just can not get it to work. Can anyone suggest how to get it working?
I am using VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

When I press Test button, the page says "Running Tests..." and nothing happens.

Cheers,
Padma

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.asoftwarecraft.com/2010/01/troubleshooting-with-fitsharp-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Check again if your path to *.dll file is correct. Probably you have a issue with path